# List Comprehension of Lists Nested in Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary where each value is a list, like so:

```
dictA = {1:['a','b','c'],2:['d','e']}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change this structure to get around my problem

I want to gather all of the entries of the lists into one single list, as follows:

```
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Additionally, I want to do this only once within an if-block.  Since I only want to do it once, I do not want to store it to an intermediate variable, so naturally, a list comprehension is the way to go.  But how?  My first guess,

```
[dictA[key] for key in dictA.keys()]
```

yields,

```
[['a','b','c'],['d','e']]
```

which does not work because

```
'a' in  [['a','b','c'],['d','e']]
```

yields `False`.  Everything else I've tried has used some sort of illegal syntax.

How might I perform such a comprehension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Loop over the returned list *too* (looping directly over a dictionary gives you keys as well):

```
[value for key in dictA for value in dictA[key]]
```

or more directly using `dictA.itervalues()`:

```
[value for lst in dictA.itervalues() for value in lst]
```

List comprehensions let you nest loops; read the above loops as if they are nested in the same order:

```
for lst in dictA.itervalues():
    for value in lst:
        # append value to the output list
```

Or use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(dictA.itervalues()))
```

The latter takes a sequence of sequences and lets you loop over them as if they were one big list. `dictA.itervalues()` gives you a sequence of lists, and `chain()` puts them together for  `list()` to iterate over and build one big list out of them.

If all you are doing is testing for membership among all the values, then what you *really* want is to a simple way to loop over all the values, and testing your value against each until you find a match. The [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) together with a suitable generator expression does just that:

```
any('a' in lst for lst in dictA.itervalues())
```

This will return `True` as soon as any value in `dictA` has `'a'` listed, and stop looping over `.itervalues()` early.

Comment: Of course, as soon as I accept your response, the problem gets more complicated.  I now need to pull all the names from nested lists within two separate dictionaries.  Can I use ```zip()``` for this?  So your solution would be ```any('a' in lst for lst in zip(dictA.itervalues(),dictB.itervalues())```

Comment: @wnnmaw: Use `itertools.chain()` again: `any('a' in lst for lst in chain(dictA.itervalues(), dictB.itervalues())`. `zip()` does something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually checking for membership (your `a in...` example), you could rewrite it as:

```
if any('a' in val for val in dictA.itervalues()):
    # do something
```

This saves having to flatten the list if that's not actually required.

Comment: It also short circuits (quits) as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see you also proposing this approach. I didn't mean to look like thief here, sorry!

Comment: @Martijn No worries... :) (I win according to the timestamp though :P)

Comment: That's because my last edit was just past the previous grace period. :-P I was not claiming first-to-post anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can just use a nested comprehension:

```
[value for key in dictA.keys() for value in dictA[key]]
```

But in general, if you've already figured out how to turn something into a nested list, you can flatten any nested iterable with [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(dictA[key] for key in dictA.keys())
```

This returns an iterator, not a list; if you need a list, just do it explicitly:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dictA[key] for key in dictA.keys()))
```

---

As a side note, `for key in dictA.keys()` does the same thing as `for key in dictA`, except that in older versions of Python, it will waste time and memory making an extra list of the keys. As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) says, `iter` on a `dict` is the same as `iterkeys`.

So, in all of the versions above, it's better to just use `in dictA` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Just because he had it in his original question; I was planning to add an explanation of why it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

In simple code just for understanding this might be helpful

```
ListA=[]
dictA = {1:['a','b','c'],2:['d','e']}
for keys in dictA:
    for values in dictA[keys]:
        ListA.append(values)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do some like ..

`output_list = []`

`[ output_list.extend(x) for x in {1:['a','b','c'],2:['d','e']}.values()]`

output_list will be ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension for its side-effects. You are wasting memory and CPU cycles here, as you are *also* building a list of `None` values.